# Getting the following error..TypeError: data type not understood while using 2D numpy array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2], [3,4])
print(a)
```

While executing, i am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: data type not understood while using 2D numpy array in python
```

What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong: `a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])`

Comment: Thank you so much..

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put all the rows in a `list`, as `array()` expects all data in its first argument, not as separate arguments for each row:

```
a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
```